# How to integrate $I = \int_{-L}^{L}\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x)\,\mathrm{dx}$ multiple ways?

Tags: integration

The integral is actually pretty easy using the identity:

$\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x\right)\,\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{(m-n)\pi}{L}\,x\right)+\sin\left(\dfrac{(m+n)\pi}{L}\,x\right)\right]$ and then integrating:

$$I  = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[-\dfrac{L}{(m-n)\,\pi}\cos\left(\dfrac{(m-n)\,\pi}{L}\right)-\dfrac{L}{(m+n)\,\pi}\cos\left(\dfrac{(m+n)\,\pi}{L}\right)\right]+C$$

But I wonder if u could achieve the same result using complex identities:

$\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x\right) = \dfrac{e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x}+e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x}}{2}$

$\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x\right) = \dfrac{e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x}-e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x}}{2\,i}$

Plugging these into the integral I get:

$I = \displaystyle{\int\dfrac{e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x}+e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,n\,x}}{2}\cdot\dfrac{e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x}-e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,m\,x}}{2\,i} = \int \dfrac{e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n+m)}}{4\,i}-\dfrac{e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(m-n)}}{4\,i}+\dfrac{e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n-m)}}{4\,i}-\dfrac{e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n+m)}}{4\,i}}$

I don't see a connection there, but I may have to solve the integral at first. More importantly: am I right so far?

**Addendum**

Integrating this also seems simple but just like a lot of  paperwork:

$\begin{align}I = &\displaystyle{\left[-\dfrac{L}{4\,(n+m)\,\pi}\,e^{i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n+m)}-\dfrac{L}{4\,(m-n)\,\pi}\,e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(m-n)}\right]}
\\
&\displaystyle{\left[+\dfrac{L}{4\,(n-m)\,\pi}\,e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n-m)}-\dfrac{L}{4\,(n+m)\,\pi}\,e^{-i\,\frac{\pi}{L}\,x\,(n+m)}\right]}\end{align}$

Comment: The formula for sine of sum of two angles would give you simple integrands: $\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)=2\sin(a)\cos(b)$

Comment: The last integral is basically a sine.

Comment: There is a mistake in what you have done so far. In $4$ terms that you got, you canceled two but they are not the same, one has $-(m+n)$ in the power and the other has $(m+n)$.

Comment: yea, right. makes it even more complicated. I really should try integrating this now.

Comment: Actually after substituting back via complex identities that integral could be the same. But there still is a sign error somewhere.

Comment: The integrand is an odd function for $m\ne 0$ and the integral is zero.

Comment: You can write $\int \exp (kx)dx=\exp(kx)/k$ for any complex $k\ne 0$ but as you said there may be a lot of paperwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{-L}^L\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi mx}{L}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
using $u=\frac{\pi x}{L}\Rightarrow dx=\frac L\pi du$ and so:
$$I=\frac L\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(nx)\sin(mx)\,\mathrm dx$$
This neatens things up somewhat. One alternative method you could try is the following.

---

Define $n=n(t),m=m(t)$ and the integral:
$$J(n,m)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(nx)\sin(mx)\,\mathrm dx$$

Taking the partial differentials we obtain:
$$
\partial^2_nJ=-\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2\cos(nx)\sin(mx)\,\mathrm dx\\
\partial^2_mJ=-\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2\cos(nx)\sin(mx)\,\mathrm dx
$$
which are equal so we know:
$$J_{nn}-J_{mm}=0$$
which yields:
$$J(n,m)=A\cos(n)\cos(m)+B\sin(n)\sin(m)$$
Then use boundary/initial conditions to find $A,B$

Comment: neat trick, using Schwarz Theorem.

Comment: Schwarz' theorem is more to do with the interchangeability of differential operators, which can be observed if we were to to find $J_{nm}$ and $J_{mn}$